# ESP32-CAM and I2C bus connection issue

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm trying to add I2C sensors to my esp cam but it doesn't work in either way.
I followed some tutorials about it and have working code but scanning the bus shows no devices.
Here is the sketch:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

#define I2C_SDA 2
#define I2C_SCL 14

//Adafruit_BME280 bme;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Setting up I2C bus");
  Wire1.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL, 100000);
  delay(100);
//  bool status1 = bme.begin(0x76, &Wire1);  
//  if (!status1) {
//    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
//  } else {
//    Serial.println("bus created.");
//  }
}

void loop() {
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;
 
  Serial.println("Scanning...");
 
  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) {
    // The i2c_scanner uses the return value of
    // the Write.endTransmisstion to see if
    // a device did acknowledge to the address.
    Wire1.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire1.endTransmission();
 
    if (error == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16)
        Serial.print("0");
        
      Serial.print(address,HEX);
      Serial.println("  !");
 
      nDevices++;
    } else if (error==4) {
      Serial.print("Unknown error at address 0x");
      if (address<16)
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  else
    Serial.println("done\n");
 
  delay(5000);           // wait 5 seconds for next scan
}
```

I tried both Wire and Wire1 objects but the effect is the same:

> Scanning... No I2C devices found

I also tied a couple of different ports with the same effect.

So my question is what is wrong here or what I possibly forgot if any. I've read that ESP32-CAM have 2 I2C buses from which second should free to use.
I ave BME280 wired up so it should be found when the bus is there but it's not found when comment out corresponding piece of setup function.

Comment: Have you made sure that you have a common ground wire between the 2 systems ?

Comment: Also, does that board need a pull up resistor or have it in-built in the board ?

Comment: Yes,I'm sure about wiring, everything is connected straight to the board so there is a common ground there. Also the board sports the MB programmer so no need for resistor. (what is that for actually ?)

Comment: Have you tried to update and upgrade your raspberry?

Comment: Raspy has nothing to do here, I'm no even using it in this case